# C# - reading Excel files giving OutOfMemory exception

Tags: c#, excel, out-of-memory, epplus

I am reading multiple excel files (large number of rows) to datatable using Epplus version 4.1

After reading a couple of excel files, it is giving System.OutOfMemoryException

Here is the code:

```
ExcelWorksheet ws;
ExcelPackage package;

package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath));   // getting OutOfMemory exception
ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

LoadToDataTable(ws, header, datatable);  // logic to load worksheet to DataTable
```

My project is currently running in "x32" mode. I tried to convert to "x64" mode and it loading all the excel files without OutOfMemory exception.
But I cannot convert the project to "x64" mode. So need a solution that works in "x32" mode.

I also tried to use 'using' statement and package.Dispose(),  but it doesn't work

```
using(package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath)))
```

Comment: Do you need to use this library, or can you switch to another library? I ask because when working with Excel files I always used ClosedXML and it always worked like a charm.

Comment: Here's the link for NuGet: [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/)